# ImportError: No module named numpy :different

Tags: python, numpy

I know this question has been asked few times, however, none of those solutions worked for me, so I thought of reposting the question in my context.

I have downloaded IDLE and Python2.7, and trying to run a python script. The above error is shown. I have verified that numpy is present somewhere in my comp., and I also tried adding 'path' (systems-advanced setting-environmental variables...), however, none of them worked.

Specific question is, is there a way I can install numpy from IDLE?.

Any inputs would greatly help to advance Science!.

Best,
Raman

Comment: What mechanism did you use to install `numpy`?  What does "I also tried adding 'path'" mean?  What did you add to your PATH variable? There are many walkthroughs on how to install python and numpy for windows, did you try referencing these?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed numpy.  It's not included with python; it's an optional extra package.  Go install it.

Answer (score 0):

As some of your comments above stated, you have not actually installed NumPy, as NumPy does not come with the base package of Python. My suggestion is to look into python package such as [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) (only for windows) because these packages come preinstalled with your main python modules (Numpy, SciPy, etc..)

BUT, to just install NumPY, either open your command prompt or a bash shell you should be able to run,

`pip install numpy`

If you dont have the command pip just run,

`python get-pip.py`